# how to add bitcoin in Peatio?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bitcoin, bitcoind, bitcoin-testnet

[image]I have created test bitcoins but how to deposit it in Peatio.

currencies.yml

```
    - id: 2
      key: satoshi
      code: btc
      symbol: "฿"
      coin: true
      quick_withdraw_max: 1000
      rpc: http://test_user_123:ddd545a1142f7fd3e167cd60e60d0a67@127.0.0.1:18332
      blockchain: https://testnet.smartbit.com.au/tx/e9d09a0401080e299c3871ba8e3bf537ab20734567cb86ea7a63d9a025b1a8f3
      address_url: https://testnet.smartbit.com.au/address/msCgLuJQNiRnXEg9AJzgpzC1qxehFNWkfH
      assets:
        balance: 3333
        accounts:
          -
            address: msCgLuJQNiRnXEg9AJzgpzC1qxehFNWkfH
```

bitcoin.conf

```
            server=1
            daemon=1

            # If run on the test network instead of the real bitcoin network
            testnet=1

            # You must set rpcuser and rpcpassword to secure the JSON-RPC api
            # Please make rpcpassword to something secure, `5gKAgrJv8CQr2CGUhjVbBFLSj29HnE6YGXvfykHJzS3k` for example.
            # Listen for JSON-RPC connections on <port> (default: 8332 or testnet: 18332)
            rpcuser=test_user_123
            rpcpassword=ddd545a1142f7fd3e167cd60e60d0a67
            rpcport=18332

            # Notify when receiving coins
            walletnotify=curl http://192.168.1.41:3000/payment_transaction/btc/%s
```

I am not able to see the balance in my bitcoin funds. What could be the reason for this?

Server trace:

```
        Started GET "/payment_transaction/btc/dc06e9864d3114ea814118f6c9b578d52f67874477ff0b546e79b360775e1117" for 192.168.1.41 at 2017-10-25 18:57:00 +0530

    ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/payment_transaction/btc/dc06e9864d3114ea814118f6c9b578d52f67874477ff0b546e79b360775e1117"):
      lib/middleware/security.rb:11:in `call'
      lib/middleware/i18n_js.rb:9:in `call'
```

Comment: are you getting an error? You think you are not getting an error, but you are. You don't know how to check it. What are you doing to check this balance? Maybe if you tell us more about what you are doing and the understanding of Peatio you have, we can help you solve this issue

Comment: @FabrizioBertoglio I am adding bitcoin in the address shown in the image from https://testnet.manu.backend.hamburg/faucet . But It is not updating here.

Comment: Same issue for me as well, did you find any solution to this?

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure why, but it seems that the bitcoind was not configured properly.

So, first I did this manually. Find the transaction IDs you did and call it manually.

1. Either you can try using the same way you are doing, just make the curl as POST request. (For me, it's `webhooks/tx`) (https://github.com/peatio/peatio/issues/79#issuecomment-44631111)
2. Another option is, you can call `/usr/local/sbin/rabbitmqadmin publish routing_key=peatio.deposit.coin payload='{"txid":"YOUR_TRANS_ID_HERE", "channel_key":"satoshi"}'`

And it shows the balance now in peatio!

Answer (score -1):

You are running peatio in testnet mode, If btc is deposited in the testnet address it won't reflect until and  unless your blockchain server not sych with your peatio server.

Or check your blockchain server status is upto date 
bitcoin-cli getblockcount